# How do I extract a substring between two characters using split()?

Tags: python, split

I'm having trouble taking out a substring located between the third occurrence of "." and the first occurrence of ":" in a line containing the word "foo". It would be helpful if someone could explain what numbers should go in the brackets and why.

```
    for line in myfile:
        if "foo" in line:
            substring=line.split('.')[].split(':')[]
            print(substring)
```

My Google searches have led me mainly to people suggesting Regex but I would rather not use that to be honest as I am a newbie at Python - I would prefer not to complicate things. I'd like to use split(). But I'm not sure what numbers to put in the brackets and every website I read just confuses me more and more.
I appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: The easiest for you to figure this out is to try by yourself, on an example of the data I think :) First look at what `line.split('.')` looks like, then select the element you want to keep in there, and keep chaining all the functions, while taking a look at every step to make sure you understand what's going on

Comment: Can you guarantee that the first occurrence of ':' is after (at least) 3 occurrences of '.'?

Comment: yes, it always is

Answer (score 0):

Given your numbers, you could try something like this:

```
for line in myfile:
    if "foo" in line:
        substring = line.split(".", 3)[3].split(":")[0]
        print(substring)

line = "a.b.c.d.e.f:foo"
s = line.split('.', 3)[3]
# "d.e.f:foo"
s.split(':')[0]
# d.e.f
```

This uses the `maxsplit` paramter of `split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)` which can limit the number of splits.

Comment: This only works if there are exactly 3 periods. For example, if the line is 'a.b.c.d.e.f:foo' the output would be 'd' whereas it should be 'd.e.f'. From the question "...substring located between the third occurrence of "." and the first occurrence of ":"" Perhaps *'.'.join(s.split('.')[3:]).split(':')[0]* would be better

Comment: @Pingu
Amended my answer to use the maxsplit param.